# Microsoft Access vba update date of record on button click

Tags: ms-access, onclick, vba, sql-insert

I have a form with combobox `cmbProjectName` where a project name can be selected from `tblProjects`.  The form also has a button `btnComplete`.

When the button is clicked, I would like to update the record for the selected project so that field `Date Modified` is filled with today's date.  I'm having trouble coding up the VBA to find the correct record to update.

The field I am looking to update is `tblProjects.[Last Modified]`, and I would like to find the record by referencing the combobox `cmbProjectName` by using the column `tblProjects.projName`.

Comment: *Welcome to Stack Overflow!*  ...so, you want to update *which* record? Based on what criteria?  The easiest way is with `DoCmd.RunSQL` but you need a it more info about the table.

Comment: I want to update the record corresponding to the project selected in cmbProjectName (e.g., WHERE tblProjects.projName = cmbProjectName).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be handled several different ways, however, it looks like you might be trying to find a VBA SQL solution. As such, try this:

```
Currentdb.Execute "UPDATE tblProjects " & _
"SET tblProjects.[Last Modified] = DATE()
WHERE tblProjects.projName = " & cmbProjectName.Value & "", dbfailonerror
```

This would of course require that the `tblProjects.projName` be a unique value for the entire table. Otherwise, you will need some other sort of solution.

Comment: I'm not seeing where this puts the date into the Date Modified field for the project.  I guess I'm needing something like "UPDATE tblProjects SET tblProjects.[Last Modified] = Date WHERE tblProjects.projName = " & cmbProjectName.

Comment: Sorry, I completed misinterpreted what you were trying to do there. The answer is updated, if I get what you mean correctly this time, this should accomplish the goal you're shooting for.